# Elastic search wildcard search space issue

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Consider index field "**ProductName**" having the value "**dove 3.75oz**" and when user searches for "dove 3.75oz" text below bool query is working fine to retreive the document:

{"bool":{"must":[{"wildcard":{"ProductName":{"value":"*dove*"}}},{"wildcard":{"ProductName":{"value":"*3.75oz*"}}}]}}

If user searches for "dove 3.75 oz" (**Space between "3.75" and "oz"**) the bool query is failing to retrieve the same document:

{"bool":{"must":[{"wildcard":{"ProductName":{"value":"*dove*"}}},{"wildcard":{"ProductName":{"value":"*3.75 oz*"}}}]}}

Question: How to design a query using a wildcard query that supports space or no spaces? Please share an example.

Comment: What is ProductName field type?

Comment: @TusharShahi ProductName field type is string

Answer (score 1):

Text fields values are broken into tokens by default and then stored. So something like "**hello man**"" will be saved separately as **hello** and **man** because of the space between them. And that is exactly why this will not work with a wildcard query.

```
{"wildcard":{"ProductName":{"value":"3.75 oz"}}}
```

It only works for single tokens. For wildcard queries you can use a special field type called [wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html#wildcard-field-type).

If you do not want to reindex your data, try phrase search like:

```
"match_phrase": {
      "ProductName": {
        "query": "3.75 oz"
      }
}
```